# iOS app black screen after exiting and re-loading

Tags: ios, ipad, multitasking

I've seen some other solutions, but none of them are working for me.

My app is suddenly returning to a black screen after I use the home button to leave and then return to the program. It briefly shows the screen and then goes black.

There's nothing inside my appDelegate methods related to foreground and background, and I don't know if there's another bit of code that I should be looking for to solve this issue.

What can cause this to happen?

update:
Upon re-entering the foreground I've checked to make sure that all of the views, subviews, layers and sublayers still exist.  Calling setNeedsDisplay to all of them from the WillEnterForeground notification does no good.

Looking at the notifications sent out, there is one called
_UIWindowWillDestroyWindowContextNotification
which looks menacing, but I can't find any information about that.

Any pointers about where to look are much appreciated, I've tried everything that seems possibly relevant.  Thanks!!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but it's very difficult to reproduce.  Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I see there are a lot of people on our boat) @olynoise did you found some solution ?

Comment: @sage444 I really don't remember!

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause is you're doing something on the main thread. When the app goes black just click pause on the debugger and check the main thread. If you're not doing something on the main thread please tell us what is your app doing when you click pause.

Comment: The screen goes black during or right before [UIApplication _handleApplicationResumeEvent:]  If i pause it, Thread 1 says "mach_msg_trap" ... don't know if that's helpful or not. Nothing happening on any other thread.

Comment: well i just don't know what the share.... the project is many pages of code, and this seemingly popped up out of nowhere.  can anything with CALayer/CAShapeLayer cause this to happen?  That's what I've been working with mostly the past few days.

Comment: What kind of things in the main thread can cause this to happen?